# Highcharts When printing the chart does not fit the page

Tags: highcharts

Is there any way to auto resize the chart to auto fit the page when printing?

It does not fit the page when I'm printing, check the image, can you see the right side of the page? It's cut. It's a common A4 page.

[image: the chart does not fit]

Btw, I'm using the print button from the chart.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug, reported: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2088

Comment: Strange, I tried the demo on the bug report, and it's fit, no problem for me. That's strange.

Comment: Legend is cutted, as I see. (Chrome last revision)

Comment: That's it, I was viewing in landscape mode, sorry ;), it's really a bug. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin-top: 9mm;
  margin-bottom: 8mm;
  margin-left: 2mm;
  margin-right: 2mm;
}
@media print {
  body {
    width: 780px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #container {
    max-width: 780px;
  }
}
```

paste this in css file.